# Tweepy filter dosen't show the all result between two dates

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, data-mining, tweepy, twitterapi-python

hey I'm trying to got the tweets has been tweeted since 1 October 2020  until today which contain 'covid' keyword which located on UK using tweepy and export it as csv file using pandas library but the result I've got only from 29 October 2020

this is the part of filtration on the code

```
import sys
import tweepy as tw
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler , Stream
import json



access_token = "xxxxxx"
access_token_secret = "xxxx"
consumer_key = "xxxxx"
consumer_secret = "xxxxx"

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)


api = tw.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

search_words ="covid"
date_since = "2020-10-01"
results = []

for tweet in tw.Cursor(api.search,tweet_mode='extended',q=search_words,lang="en",
                       since=date_since,geocode='51.745719,-1.236599,300km').items(9000):
    results.append(tweet.created_at)


print(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Tweepy's search method uses Twitter's legacy standard search API, which can only fetch up to 7 days history of Tweets. You will need to use the 30-day search option (the [`API.search_30_day`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#API.search_30_day) method), which will also require you to configure a premium search environment in the Twitter developer portal. Note that the [search operators and syntax for premium search](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/api-reference/premium-search) are different to those in standard search.